# When will Breeze support Entity Framework 6?

Tags: breeze, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

The final version of Visual Studio 2013 is finally here, along with the final version of Entity Framework 6.
When will Breeze release an update supporting Entity Framework 6? Is it going to be anytime soon? Weeks? A couple of months?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a release date of a third-party library - **NOT** about programming....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated 10/28/2013:

As of now, Breeze 1.4.5 has support for Microsoft's ASP.NET WebApi 2 and Entity Framework 6. Please see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download.

### Old post...

It's coming in our next release. This should be within a few weeks.